# element.on($destroy) shows element is not defined in angular

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I am trying to cancel the $interval event in my directive while changing the route or state of the application. I found this code which could act in destroy event.

But this returns my element is not defined. Do I have to inject any service or directive in the controller.

```
element.on('$destroy', function() {
          console.log("cancelling interval");
          $interval.cancel(promise);
        });
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: element is not defined
    at new Controller (http://localhost:port/src/controller.js
    at invoke (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4182:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4190:27)
    at http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8453:28
    at $interpolate.compile (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3897:28)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8217:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7726:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:port/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7075:13)
```

Thanks in advance
Code is pretty long, so posting the snipper where is called.
Updated:

```
   (function ()
   { 
   'use strict'; 
   angular .module('app')
   .controller('Controller', Controller); 
   Controller.$inject = ['Service', '$modal', '$interval', '$scope']; 
   function Controller(Service, $modal, $interval, $scope)
   { 
     console.log("Beginning");
     var ctrl = this;
     $scope.headerName= "Header Name";
     ctrl.selected = {};
     setupData(); 
     var promise = $interval(setupData, 1000000);
     $scope.on('$destroy', function()
     { 
     $interval.cancel(promise); 
     });
```

Comment: The code is inside a controller `function Controller($scope, $interval){ //element.on($destroy) }`   Well I tried doing this `function($scope, $interval, element)`, but this is returns `on is not defined`

Comment: you need to use `$scope.on('$destroy', ..`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, its returned `$scope.on is not defined`

Comment: are you sure? which angular version do you use?

Comment: I have installed bower components in my project.

Comment: If Some one is giving downvote, then you should post the answer for this. Then no mean downvoting the question.  I am new to angualrJS

Comment: Issue has to do with where is this called. Show the full context of this code. If `element` is undefined there's something else wrong and not enough code is shown

Comment: Looking at `function($scope, $interval, element)` element isn't injectable in controller...need a lot more information as to what you think it is

Comment: `(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Controller', Controller);
    Controller.$inject = ['Service', '$modal', '$interval', '$scope'];
    function Controller(Service, $modal, $interval, $scope) {
        console.log("Beginning");
        var ctrl = this;
        $scope.headerName= "Header Name";
        ctrl.selected = {};
        setupData();
        var promise = $interval(setupData, 1000000);

        $scope.on('$destroy', function() {                      $interval.cancel(promise);
        });`

Comment: The code you found will only work in a directive. A controller knows nothing about elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$scope.$on('$destroy'..)` and the interval timer will be removed when a new route is initialized:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      console.log("cancelling interval");
      $interval.cancel(promise);
});
```

WIthin the comments above the attempt at using `$scope.on()` was incorrect as all angular internal events methods use `$` prefix

Comment: Yeah, Just now I found in the angular documentation. Thanks :)

Comment: lesson learned I hope about providing all the relevant code in the question....saves a lot of confusion and comments... good luck

Comment: Yes Charlietfl!! Sorry about that!